# How to convert sql statement into dplyr notation?

Tags: sql, r, join, dplyr

I troubled to convert sql statement into dplyr.
Suppose I have the following sql statement:

```sql
select * from table1 t1 
left join table2 t2 on t1.id1 = t2.id2
where t2.id is null
```

The dplyr notation is:

```r
data <- table1 %>%
  left_join(table2, by = c('id1' = 'id2') %>%
  filter(is.null(id2))
```

However it doesn't work.
How can I modify my `dplyr` statement to correspond the above mentioned sql statement?

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/

Comment: I think instead of `is.null` you need `is.na`. Try with `%>% filter(is.na(id2))`

Answer (score 1):

This issue could be resolved with the `anti_join`:

```
data<- table1 %>%
anti_join(table2, by = c('id1' = 'id2')
```